# Spark streaming: expose spark_streaming_* metrics

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus

We are using spark on kubernetes (using the SparkOperator) and Prometheus to expose the metrics of the application. The application is a spark streaming app (NOT structured streaming).
The application used to run on an image with spark version 2.4.7 and was later migrated to spark 3.1.2.
Because of this migration all `spark_streaming_*` metrics disappeared, like `spark_streaming_driver_totalreceivedrecords` (as defined here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingSource.scala#L53)

In general the Prometheus setup seems to work because when you curl the prometheus port you can still see a bunch of other metrics - just none of the spark streaming metrics.
The spark-image contains the prometheus-java agent and in the helm chart of the stream-app the monitoring spec is configured to use it

```
monitoring:
    exposeDriverMetrics: true
    exposeExecutorMetrics: true
    prometheus:
      jmxExporterJar: "/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar"
      port: 8888
```

as described in the docu of the spark-operator https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#monitoring.
This is also how the setup used to work with spark 2.4.7

Are this metrics gone in spark3? Or are we maybe just missing some configuration?
Another side note: when you check the metrics via `<spark-driver>:<ui-port>/metrics/json` you can see the desired metrics

Answer (score 1):

ok it seems the spark-operator currently is not working properly with the current metrics in Spark3.
The issue could be fixed by provisioning the spark-image with a fixed prometheus configuration file and then use it in your helm chart

```
monitoring:
    exposeDriverMetrics: true
    exposeExecutorMetrics: true
    prometheus:
      jmxExporterJar: "/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar"
      port: 8888
      configFile: PATH_TO_THE_CONFIG
```

more infos and a working prometheus config can be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/1117